# How do I use Jasmine to spy on a function that is imported via an ES6 default export?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6, redux

I am working on a Redux app & trying to create a spy using Jasmine on an ES6 default exported function. I have attempted a few different ways of spying on the function, including using a wildcard import to access the 'default' property of the import, but nothing I've tried has worked thus far. Below is an example, where I would want to test `widgets.js` and spy on the widget function. Is there a way to achieve this without having to change the way im exporting the function from `widget.js`?

**widget.js**

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import { CREATE_WIDGET } from 'actions';

const initialState = Map({
  id: undefined,
  name: undefined
});

export default function widget(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_WIDGET:
      return state.update((widget) => widget.merge(action.widget));

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**widgets.js**

```
import { OrderedMap } from 'immutable';
import { CREATE_ROOM } from 'actions';
import widget from './widget';

const initialState = OrderedMap();

export default function widgets(state=initialState, action={}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_ROOM:
      return state.set(action.widget.id, widget(undefined, action));

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a way of doing what you want to do with a named export? They're not that different actually.

Comment: No, I don't. I was told about this plugin, however, I have not been able to get it running correctly and feel like I may just have to export the function as a method on an object.

Answer (score 42):

You say you tried importing the wildcard and spying on default?  What was the issue with that approach?  I just ran into this problem and doing this solved it for me:

```
import * as widget from './widget';

describe('widget spec', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(widget, 'default');
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem with this is you remove the ability to have tree-shaking occur when you build.  You want to be as optimized as you can by just importing the part you are actually using.

Comment: it does not really matter because production code should not include testing files anyways

Comment: i'm getting an error "is not declared writable or has no setter".

Comment: Haven't tried with default exported functions, but `spyOnProperty(widget, 'default').and.callThrough()` could work for you as it did me.

Answer (score 2):

jasmine has some issues spying on individually exported functions so the typical work around I have found is this. Hope this helps people

```
import * as Funcs from './funcs.ts';
const myFuncSpy : jasmine.Spy = jasmine.createSpy( 'myFunc' ).and.returnValue( <SOME_VALUE> );
spyOnProperty( Funcs, 'myFunc', 'get' ).and.returnValue( myFuncSpy );
```